# $_POST not getting number zero

Tags: php, html, post

I have the following code inside a form whereby when press submit button, php side is grabbing the input value using `$_POST['revisionCad']`.

```html
<form method="POST">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Revision" name="revisionCad" id="revisionCad" min="0">

    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Save" type="submit" style="width:200px;">Create/Change Revision</button>
</form>
```

**My Issue**

Everything working fine except when I gave number 0 as input, `$_POST` is getting no value. My error check telling, please enter a number.
Below is my error check code

```
if(isset($_POST['revisionCad'])){
    $revisionCad = $_POST['revisionCad'];  
}

if(empty($revisionCad)){
    erDisplay('Please select a revision for Cadgui');
}
```

But any number greater than 0, `$_POST['revisionCad']` is grabbing correctly. I tried to remove the `min` attribute as well as change to -1. But still whenever I enter number 0, `$_POST['revisionCad']` not grabbing any value. Anyone knows why?

Comment: try if (is_numeric($var)){}

Comment: do try and read the documentation for the empty function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: You have to add an additional other check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain why this is happening, you have to take a closer look at the PHP `empty()` function. From the documentation we see that (emphasis mine)...

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or **if its value equals FALSE**.

In PHP, the value of zero is a falsy value. So you get the following output,

```
var_dump(false == 0); // Outputs "true"
var_dump(empty(0));   // Outputs "true"
```

So you need to alter your code to check if the variable is set and greater or equal to zero, which you can do by altering the snippet you showed to the following.

```
if (isset($_POST['revisionCad']) && $_POST['revisionCad'] >= 0) {
    $revisionCad = $_POST['revisionCad'];
} else {
    erDisplay('Please select a revision for Cadgui');
}
```

- http://php.net/empty

Comment: Its also worth a mention that if its a 0 as a possible expected result, typecast post to a string `(string) $_POST[];`  then Empty() wont try to evaluate is as a booloean false

Comment: The string of zero and the integer of zero is treated the same in PHP, as PHP is not a strongly typed language. Hence, `empty("0")` is still true.

Comment: Thank you Qirel. I added the condition `if(!isset($_POST['revisionCad']) || $_POST['revisionCad'] < 0)` then show error message. Didn't know that empty function still count number 0 as empty

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the condition as below:

```
if(isset($revisionCad) && $revisionCad >=0){
    erDisplay('Please select a revision for Cadgui');
}
```

Actually [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function treats 0 as empty value so it gives this error.

Comment: With your code, it will display an error message when the value is empty, when its zero or any positive number. So it will effectively only accept negative numbers.

Comment: @GufranHasan Thank you. Although the logic you gave was not what I want, but I got the idea that empty function still count number 0 as empty from your comment

Answer (score 1):

Add a default value to your form or change it in your code dynamically as follow:

```
<form method= "POST">
<!-- <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Revision" name="revisionCad" id="revisionCad" min="0"> -->

/** Assign default value or set it automatically in your code.**/
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Revision" name="revisionCad" id="revisionCad" min="0" value=0>

<button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Save" type="submit" style="width:200px;">Create/Change Revision</button>
</form>
```

Your PHP codes:

```
if(isset($_POST['revisionCad'])){
  $revisionCad = $_POST['revisionCad'];  
}


if(empty($revisionCad)){
    erDisplay('Please select a revision for Cadgui');
    }
```

Should be changed to :

```
    // You can set a default value of 0 in the code or leave it at null;
    $revisionCad = (isset($_POST['revisionCad']) && !empty( $_POST['revisionCad'] ) || $_POST['revisionCad'] >=0 ) ? 
    trim($_POST['revisionCad']) : null;


/* Check if data is set to default null by your script,
 * Display error, since no data was received
 */
if(is_null($revisionCad))
{
  erDisplay('Please select a revision for Cadgui');
}

// if no error, continue with the rest of the codes ...
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give 0 in value property as default value.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Revision" name="revisionCad" id="revisionCad" min="0" value="0">
```

Comment: This does not account for the issues with `empty(0)` being `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(!isset($revisonCad))` . I hope it works.
Since you have given `empty()` function, it treat 0 as empty value. Hence, no input is grabbed.